# Boostrap media list, how to get items to scroll horizontally?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and have created a media list in a side bar.

```
<aside class="col-md-4">
    <div class="content">
        <ul class="media-list">
            <li class="media">
            <li class="media">
            <li class="media">
```

on medium/large screens I get a column which takes up a third of the page, the media items in this column are position on top of each other.

On a small device the column is now 100% width of the screen and the media items behave the same way.

However what I am trying to do is keep the media items 100%, but have them position side by side, so that the user must scroll horizontally to see the next item.

I have tried

```
.media { float:left; display:inline }
```

different variations will get the media items to display side by side but they will not be 100% of the screen and will not go off screen, so when an item reaches the end of the page the next item will be displayed underneath rather than out of the view port.

So how could I for example, set

```
 .media {width:100%; float:left;}
 .media-list {width: auto; overflow-x: scroll}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: would something like [this](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units) help?

Answer (score 0):

```
.media-list {
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
white-space: nowrap; }

.media {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 100%; }
```

this works.